# <!DOCKTYPE... is not valid JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, put

Simply put, i have a list on a server containing multiple tupples of data.
I have a 'check' function which updates a datapoint in the tupple from 0 to 1,
so basically it updates/edits the json from 0 to 1.
However using PUT (node.js) i cant get it to work.

My html contains of a ul with li where the li-elements retrieve data from the server. The li-elements does also contain buttons, where one of the buttons 'checks' the li and furthermore should  update the data.check to 1.

```
async function checkKolonist(evt) {
 let dataId = evt.target.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("data-id");
 fetch('/venteliste')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].id == dataId) {
                if (data[i].check !== 1) {
                    evt.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove("notchecked");
                    evt.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add("checked");
                    data[i].check = 1;
                } else {
                    evt.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add("notchecked");
                    evt.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove("checked");
                    data[i].check = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        fetch('/venteliste', {
                method: 'PUT',
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(updatedData => {
                console.log('Data updated successfully:', updatedData);
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error updating data:', error));
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
```

}

```
app.put('/venteliste/:id', updateKolonisterHandler);

function updateKolonisterHandler(request, response) {
 let kolonistId = parseInt(request.params.id);
 let updatedKolonist = request.body;
 let dataId = updatedKolonist['data-id'];

 for (let i = 0; i < venteliste.length; i++) {
    // Compare kolonistId with the value of data-id attribute
    if (venteliste[i].id === dataId) {
        venteliste[i] = updatedKolonist;
        response.status(200).json({ status: 'success', message: 'Kolonist updated       successfully' });
        return;
    }
}

// Send a 404 status code with error message including variable values
let errorMessage = `Kolonist ID ${kolonistId} not found in venteliste. Data ID: ${dataId}`;
response.status(404).json({ status: 'error', message: errorMessage });
}


console.log errors: 

venteliste.js:156     PUT http://localhost:8080/venteliste 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ venteliste.js:156
Promise.then (async)
checkKolonist @ venteliste.js:142
venteliste.js:167 Error updating data: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is.             not valid JSON
(
```

Comment: HTML is indeed not valid JSON and can't be parsed as such.  Presumably you're seeing this error client-side in the browser?  Now is a good time to start using your browser's debugging tools.  *Most likely* you're making an AJAX request and expecting JSON in the response, but receiving HTML in the response.  Your next step would be to determine why the server is responding with HTML for that particular request.

Comment: This part is likely the most important: `PUT http://localhost:8080/venteliste 404 (Not Found)`  The PUT operation on the server appears to be expecting an `id` value on the URL, but the client-side code isn't providing one.  Something like: `http://localhost:8080/venteliste/123`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your url handler, `app.put('/venteliste/:id', updateKolonisterHandler);` is looking for an `:id` param, but when you call `fetch`, you're not providing one, so there's, effectively, no matching url for it to call a handler on. You need to either provide the `id` param in your `fetch` or create a new url handler for just the `/venteliste` end point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My checkKolonist function has the evt as param which where it creates the id specificly out from that 'evt.target.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("data-id");', how come this not enough?

Comment: Because you're not using that value in the actual `fetch`.  When `fetch` sends the HTTP request to your server, it's asking for a page at `/venteliste`. The server takes the request and tries to find a handler that matches the requested url (`/venteliste`) but the only url pattern is knows how to match is the pattern `/venteliste/*id*`. Since there's no `id`, it's technically not a match, so the server sends back a `404: 'Page Not Found` error.  Add the `dataId` to your url and you should see your handler triggered.

Comment: perhaps a stupid question, however is it possible not having the /id, meaning:
app.put('/venteliste', updateKolonisterHandler);

Comment: The url pattern matcher is regex based. Simply adding a `?` will tell the match that the param is optional, ala `app.put('/venteliste/:id?`, fooFunc)`. However, it means that any attempts to retrieve that value will fail for a url that doesn't include it. Make sense?